# Add comments to profiles

Tags: users, comments

How do you allow users to add comments to your profile page? I'm already using content profile module but I don't know how to add comments to it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Go to admin > content types, find your content type used as a profile (default is called 'profile') and click edit.  Scroll down to the "Comment Settings" fieldset and expand that and choose "Read/Write" and any other comment options you choose and save the content type.

[image: Content Profile Comments]