# Allow comments on profile pages

Tags: 7, users, comments

What are the ways to allow comments on user profile pages in Drupal 7? There is a profile content module, which unfortunately is not available for Drupal 7.

Comment: That question was for drupal 6.

Comment: No. Please check it once. OP clearly mentioned that it for D7. May I know how could you justify that the question was asked for D6?

Comment: @KrishnaMohan Subliminal messaging - cast your eye to the left of that page...3 sixes in a vertical row ;)

Comment: @Clive  I just noticed that ;) :) :)

Comment: @KrishnaMohan my bad. I thought that it was marked as a duplicate of this (http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/10767/add-comments-to-profiles) which was what was shown as a duplicate suggestion when I was typing the question. I was in a hurry to cross section. My apologies.

Comment: @RanaPrathap Hey, no problem. I just wanted to intimate you. :) :)

Answer (score 0):

I think you can find an answer in this similar question here: [How do I enable comments for user profiles?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/11526/how-do-i-enable-comments-for-user-profiles)

Apparently, [Profile2](http://drupal.org/project/profile2) module allows that functionnality.

Answer (score 0):

Generally Drupal allows comments on nodes.
There is a module in D7 module [User Proifile Comments](https://www.drupal.org/project/user_profile_comments) which does the job.

You can also check this https://www.drupal.org/node/68340 which was a more customized way.